# Complex Green's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I want to integrate $\int_{\partial R} |e^{zt}|dz$ where $R\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is a rectangle whose sides are parallel to the coordinate axes. I want to use a complex version of green's theorem, but I keep getting an imaginary solution, which doesn't seem right.

The formula I have is $\oint_C f(z)dz=i\int \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dA$.

Say the rectangle $R=\{x+iy:a\leq x\leq b, c\leq y\leq d\}$

$\int_{\partial R} |e^{zt}|dz=\int_{\partial R} e^{xt}dz=i\int_R te^{xt} \ dA=it\int_a^b\int_c^de^{xt}dydx\in \{Re(z)=0\}$

Am I doing something wrong, or is my intuition off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intuition is off. Since $t$ is real, the integrand takes identical values on the two sides of the rectangle parallel to the  real axis, and since the two sides are traversed in opposite direction, these integrals cancel. We are left with the integrals over the sides parallel to the imaginary axis, where the integrand $\lvert e^{zt}\rvert$ is real (of course), and the differential $dz$ is purely imaginary, $dz = \pm i\,dy$ there, since the real part is constant. So the integral must be purely imaginary.